# Faster alternative to perform Pandas groupby.apply with a multiple conditions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30], 
                   "Revenue": [90, 89, 80, 95, 99, 59, 70, 95, 78, 85, 82, 71, 78, 88],
                   "Chance": [True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False],
                   "City": ["Strasbourg", "Koln", "Alger", "Casa", "Mosco", "London", "Montpellier", "Barcelone", "Lyon", "Madrid", "Milan", "NYC", "Torino", "Paris"]
                  })
```

[image]

The df should be grouped by ID and 2 columns should be created as follows:
-'NotAccepted' cities: cities which have: *'Revenue' below 84* **OR** *'Chance' is False*:
-'Accepted' cities are the rest.
I have to concatenate the names of all 'Accepted' and 'NotAccepted' cities into these columns. (Please check the final photo below)

My solution is as follows:

```
df_result=df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: pd.Series({
    'NotAccepted': [','.join(g['City'][(g['Chance'] == False) | (g['Revenue'] < 84)])],                                          
    'Accepted': [','.join(g['City'][(g['Chance'] == True) & (g['Revenue'] >= 84)])],
                                             })).reset_index()
```

[image]

The real df is actually large and takes a long time to group/apply.
**Is there a faster alternative than my solution?** Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just build a col before `groupby`

```
df['new'] = np.where((df['Chance'] == False) | (df['Revenue'] < 84),'NotAccepted','Accepted')
out = df.groupby(['ID','new'])['City'].agg(list).unstack(fill_value=[])
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is actually much faster. Is there a way to get the exact output dataframe as mine? ( 1- empty lists instead of NaN. 2- The dataframe index )

Comment: @kenoussiyahya check the update

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I should only fix the index now.

Comment: @kenoussiyahya out.reset_index(inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

Use Dask Groupby - I faced a similar issue and received about 1 order of magnitude speedup. This allows you to run across multiple CPUs rather than being single-thread bound.

https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html

I would imagine there are ways to send to GPU/multi-node as well.